# How to set up Author archives with sub category URL

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

So i have a site where i have used the authors.php page so that i can display individual user's profile pages.. the url then looks something like:
http://mydomain.com/author/test/

What i would like to do is have it so that I can add subpages to this that are common for each user ie:
http://mydomain.com/author/test/liked-posts/ where i can add all the posts that the user has liked ie: liked-posts.php

is there a place i should be telling URL's of this structure to be redirecting to a specific file? and how would i do that?

This is the complete code that im using to query my posts:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Posts liked by Author
 *
 * for a child theme of Twenty_Twelve
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">

        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wti_like_post WHERE user_id = {$author->ID}" );
if( strpos( $wp_query->query_vars['liked-posts'] ,'page') !== false ) {
    $paged = substr( $wp_query->query_vars['liked-posts'], 5 );
}

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post__in' => $post_ids
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query( $args ); ? >

            <?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

   <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?> 



            <?php else : ?>
            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
                </header>

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

            <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: search for questions using [`add_rewrite_endpoint`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint), pretty sure there's one on this site detailing author endpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can use [`add_rewrite_endpoint`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) to accomplish this.

First, add the endpoint:

```
function wpa_author_endpoints(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'liked-posts', EP_AUTHORS );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_author_endpoints' );
```

After flushing rewrite rules (visit your `Settings > Permalinks` page in admin), author URLs can now be appended with `/liked-posts/`.

Next, add a filter to `author_template` to load a different template for these requests. This checks if the request has set the `liked-posts` query var, and loads the template `liked-posts.php` if it exists:

```
function wpa_author_template( $template = '' ){
    global $wp_query;
    if( array_key_exists( 'liked-posts', $wp_query->query_vars ) )
        $template = locate_template( array( 'liked-posts.php', $template ), false );
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'author_template', 'wpa_author_template' );
```

Within that template, you can use [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) to fetch the author data for the queried author, which you can use in additional queries to load your author data.

EDIT - pagination doesn't work with an endpoint, because anything after the endpoint gets put into the endpoint query var. so to get the page number, just extract it from the query var:

```
if( strpos( $wp_query->query_vars['liked-posts'] ,'page') !== false ) {
    echo substr( $wp_query->query_vars['liked-posts'], 5 );
}
```

Comment: Excelent answer my friend!! But my pagination doesnt work when i go to author/admin/liked-posts/page/2/ , author/admin/liked-posts/page/3/ and so on... Is there and extra rule for that?

Comment: nvm i just did it! ->     $author_rules['author/([^/]+)/liked-posts/?$'] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]';
    $author_rules['author/([^/]+)/liked-posts/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
return $author_rules;

Comment: see edit above for pagination without adding a rewrite rule.

Comment: Milo i added if( strpos( $wp_query->query_vars['liked-posts'] ,'page') !== false ) {
    echo substr( $wp_query->query_vars['liked-posts'], 5 );
} into my functions.php and my pagination still not working :/

Comment: the code I added just outputs the page number as an example, it won't work as-is. change `echo` to `$page =` and use that in your query for the `paged` argument. you also have to add `global $wp_query` if you're trying to access `$wp_query` within a function.

Comment: This is my query ...         <?php
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wti_like_post WHERE user_id = {$author->ID}" );
 $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post__in' => $post_ids
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query( $args ); ?>

Comment: edit your question with your complete code. the paged query var doesn't exist, so you can't get the pagination value from there, that's what the code in my edit is for.

Comment: Milo i edited my question and added my entire template with the code. I also used your code to create the $paged query var but still not working.

Comment: nvm Milo! I got it working now! i made a mistake trying to create the paged query var.. I got it done now and its working like a charm! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!